# Rails 4 join query with predetermined objects found by geolocation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-4

**Models**

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trial
end

s_locs = Location.near(...) # => This returns a collection of Geocoded locations via the geocoder gem
```

How do I write a join query the trials of all "Prehistoric" locations?  Basically, I'm looking for a way to get the set of unique parents (trials) of the associated locations.  I know something like this is how you write join queries:

```
Trial.joins("LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.trial_id = trials.id")
```

I want to write something like the below, but I know that's not the way.

```
Trial.joins("LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.trial_id = trials.id AND locations = s_locs")
```

If there's a "Rails 4" way as well as a more SQL-like way, I'd like to see both as I'm trying to learn SQL a bit better.